# Confusion on definition of differential

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I’m having a hard time understanding a certain section in In Ordinary Differential Equations by Tenenbaum and Pollard.

Specifically, in section 6, they state the following:

Given a function $y=f(x)$,

They define the differential dy as:

$dy=f’(x) \Delta x $ (6.14)

And denote the function dy as $(dy)(x, \Delta x)$ as it is a function of $x$ and $\Delta x.$

They then state that if $y=\hat{x}$, where  (and this distinction is completely lost on me in the sense of not understanding why it is necessary), “we place the symbol ^ over x so that $y=\hat{x}$ will define a function that assigns to each value of the independent variable x the same unique value to the dependent variable y.”

They then say that if $y=\hat{x}$, then $(dy)(x, \Delta x) = (d \hat{x})(x, \Delta x) = \Delta x.$ (6.22)

All of this is fine I suppose but I don’t understand the logic at all behind the next step:

“If I’m (6.14) we replace $\Delta x$ by its value as given in (6.22), it becomes

$(dy)(x, \Delta x) = f’(x) (d \hat{x})(x, \Delta x)$ (6.24)

This part doesn’t make any sense to me as they are simultaneously stating that $y=f(x)$ and $y=\hat{x}$ by saying so, unless I misunderstood something.

And finally, this last part also completely evades me:

They state that the above relation is correct (still not sure why based on their reasoning), however “it became customary to write (6.24) in the more familiar form

$dy = f’(x) dx $ or $\frac{dy}{dx} = f’(x)$.

This last part especially confuses me because now it can no longer be said they were defining dy as a function, but were using its definition as a limit in the conventional sense of a derivative. I’ve seen posts about why this symbolic manipulation of dy and dx turns out to be ok because of the chain rule, but I’m more just lost on any and all of the steps they took in introducing this differential.

If anyone could help clarify that would be great, thank you!

Comment: This appears to be incorrect or pseudo-historical reconstruction (perhaps ask on hsm.SE). It is of course technically correct to write $d f(x;\Delta x)=f'(x)\Delta x=f'(\hat x(x))d\hat x(x;\Delta x)$ and then leave the arguments out to get $df=f'(\hat x)\,dx$. But Leibniz when introducing his differential quotients was arguing in terms of infinitesimal numbers, not in terms of linear forms or linear functions or directional derivatives or some other generalized derivations.

Comment: (6.14) is *not* a definition unless you've made precise $dy$, $\Delta x$, which usually isn't the case in this context

Comment: $dy=f'(x)\Delta x, d\hat{x}=\Delta x \Rightarrow dy=f'(x) d\hat{x}$, then change $d\hat{x}$ to $dx$ to obtain last expression

Comment: $y=\hat{x}$ is used only to obtain $d\hat{x}=\Delta x$

Comment: Just as a note - if you are interested in why the traditional notation works in the modern context from an infinitesimal perspective, check out Fite's "Total and Partial Differentials" paper.  https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.07958

Comment: Thank you for the responses everyone! Oh I see about $d \bar{x} = \Delta x$. Thank you for the clarification @IvanKaznacheyeu. And consider me a hyperrealist johnnyb :), thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a function $f$, and the relation $y = f(x)$. We define the differential $\text dy$ at a point $p$ and displacement $v$ as

$$ \text dy(p,v) = f'(p) \cdot v $$

What this does is give a family of linear approximations of $y$, one for each starting point $p$. This is because $f'(p)$ is *defined* to be the slope (in this one-variable case) of the best-approximation line of $f$ at $p$.

Now, a little transparency into what the author is trying to do here. Usually, you see the differential defined as

$$ \text dy = f'(x) \ \text dx $$

especially with regard to integration, so they are trying to "justify" this notation. In particular, if we have $f$ as the identity function, i.e. $y = f(x) = x$, we *should* have

$$ \text dx = \text dx $$

Indeed, using the above definition, we have

$$ \text dx(p,v) = v $$

so that $\text dx$ is always just $v$. So, he says, we just *call* that $v$ value $\text dx(p,v)$ in *all* cases, so that we get the above relation. That is, replace $p$ with $x$ (it's just a variable name, after all) and "hide" the function arguments, and we get

$$ \text dy = f'(x) \ \text dx $$

This gives us the ability to see the Liebniz notation as more than just a notation. Since $\text dy$ and $\text dx$ are real-valued functions, they can be manipulated like real numbers. So, as long as $\text dx \neq 0$, we can write

$$ \frac{\text dy}{\text dx} = f'(x) $$

Note that this is *not* an accurate historical account. Instead, it's what Grant Sanderson calls "discovery fiction". It is a sequence of steps that *could* lead to some mathematical idea or standard, but isn't necessarily how it happened. It's purpose is to give a simpler motivation for something which has a messier and more complicated historical foundation.

Comment: Ahh I see! Thank you!